# Filter numpy array based on existence in dictionary

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy ndarray as follows:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1, 2, 1], [4, 5, 7], [3, 2, 3]])
```

I have a dictionary which keeps some class IDs as follows:

```
k = {1: None, 2: None, 3: None}
```

Now, the last column of that numpy array holds the class IDs. So what I would like to do is filter the numpy array based on whether the class IDs exists in the dictionary. So, filtering that input array would give the 1st and 3rd row as `7` is not in the dictionary.

So I get the classes column as :

```
cls = x[:, -1]
```

Now, I am stuck as to how to use this to filter the `x` array without looping through this and creating another array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way with [`numpy.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html):

```
keys = list(k.keys())
res = x[np.in1d(x[:, -1], keys)]

print(res)

[[1 2 1]
 [3 2 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something such as:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1, 2, 1], [4, 5, 7], [3, 2, 3]])
k = {1: None, 2: None, 3: None}
classes = [i for i in x[:,-1] if i in k.keys()]
classes = np.array(classes)
print(classes)
```

This should return 1 and 3, and not 7 since we are only looking for the last row of data values in x. This will return a list of the values that are in k and you can form it into an array if you choose.